# Null List in Pester Mock created from a closure

Tags: powershell, pester

Why does the following code:

```
  function CreateExecutedCommandsLogger(){
     param(
        [System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]]$cmdLog
     )
     "WWWWW=>{0}" -f $cmdLog | Write-Host
     return{
        param(
           [parameter(valuefrompipeline)]$command
        )
        "XXXXX=>{0}" -f $command | Write-Host
        "YYYYY=>{0}" -f $cmdLog | Write-Host
        $cmdLog.Add($command)
     }.GetNewClosure()
  }

  $executedCommands = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]
  Mock ExecuteSqlCommand (CreateExecutedCommandsLogger $executedCommands)
```

Result in the error:

```
  RuntimeException: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
  at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 7
  at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Users\notme\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\Functions\Mock.ps1: line 1018
  at ExecuteBlock, C:\Users\notme\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\Functions\Mock.ps1: line 1022
  at Invoke-Mock, C:\Users\notme\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\Functions\Mock.ps1: line 868
  at <ScriptBlock><Process>, <No file>: line 53
```

For reference the tracing output gives:

```
WWWWW=>System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
XXXXX=>C:\dummy\command.exe -S "blah" -d "blahblah" -i "something.sql"
YYYYY=>
```

When I use the following, it works:

```
  $dummyMock = (CreateExecutedCommandsLogger $executedCommands)
  &$dummyMock "blah"
```

I'm assuming this is something to do with the way the script block in the mock is executed?

Comment: If you type `(gcm Mock).ScriptBlock`, then you can see following line: `$mockWithCopy = [scriptblock]::Create($MockWith.ToString())` and it is the only usage of `$MockWith` in whole script. So, `$MockWith` effectively is a string, any closure ignored.

Comment: If you pop that as an answer I'll mark it correct. Now to understand the how's and why's of that bit of code in Pester.

Comment: Hmm, interesting... never considered this case when I wrote that code.  Pester supports injecting mocks into script modules with the `-ModuleName` parameter or the `InModuleScope` command, which is where that code comes from, but it assumes that if you don't use either of those options, the script block's scope is the same as the test script.  Closures invalidate that assumption.  I'll see if I can make it work without breaking anything else.

Comment: This might turn out to be a very simple fix: https://github.com/pester/Pester/pull/465.  Running a build now to make sure existing tests all continue to work on psv2-v5, and will add some tests around the closure bits next (though I've already tested a bit on my computer with success.)

Will sleep on it and see if I can think of any ways to break it.

Comment: Thanks @DaveWyatt - will give that a whizz. Great response to the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from source `(Get-Command Mock).ScriptBlock`, there is single line where `$MockWith` parameter is used:

```
$mockWithCopy = [scriptblock]::Create($MockWith.ToString())
```

So that, `$MockWith` effectively is a string and any closure ignored. Likely it is done because on next line newly created script block `$mockWithCopy` bounded to some session state, thus you loose your closure anyway:

```
Set-ScriptBlockScope -ScriptBlock $mockWithCopy -SessionState $contextInfo.Session
```

Pester first do private copy of script block to not affect passed instance.